# Can I use HTML and CSS to wrap text through a circle?

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

Newbie here, so I apologize if this is a simple answer. I come from the print world where we would often use a circle or half-circle behind the opening paragraph of text. Is is possible to do the same thing in HTML5 & CSS3?

I have the code for creating the circle and for styling it, but I don't know how to make the text show up on top of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `border-radius:50%` on a div containing your text. Or isn't that what you mean?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>this is content</p>
    </div>
</body>

div {background:red;height:50px;width:50px;border-radius:50%;padding:5%;text-align:center;}
p {margin:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NAvbX/

Comment: I am an idiot. I put the close div before the paragraph. No wonder it wouldn't work.